# App appears behind Xcode when running

Tags: xcode, cocoa

When I run my cocoa application on Xcode 4.3.3. using Lion 10.7.4. The application starts and appears behind Xcode. Few times it appears on front, not sure whats going on. Any one had an issue like this ? My main NSWindow is a borderless window.

Comment: It's difficult determining the reason why your app fails to appear in front without seeing the relevant code from your app delegate class and/or the window class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following line during launch:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```